# Sequence Function in WPS spreadsheet. Only shows 1 cell

Tags: wps-office

When I try to use the function sequence in spreadsheets like in  excel, it only shows 1 result, how can I make wps to allow overflow in cells?

Comment: WPS Office is a proprietary app. Also consider contacting WPS support

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what you are trying to do. Can you edit the question and add more details? Edit link: https://askubuntu.com/posts/1488391/edit

Answer (score 1):

Sequence is an array function and you need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination to make it work in WPS Office.

Reference: https://www.wps.com/blog/ctrl-shift-enter-and-array-formulas-in-excel-a-comprehensive-guide/